# Is the eigenvalue problem underdetermined?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The basic problem in linear algebra is solving $Ax=b$, where constant $A$ is $n\times n$, the unknown $x$ is $n\times1$, and constant $b$ is $n\times1$.
So there are $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns.

$Ax=x$ is still $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns.

But the eigenvalue problem $Ax=cx$, $c$ being the scalar eigenvalue, is very different.

We don’t know the eigenvalues. And there could be up to n distinct eigenvalues, and along with them $n$ $n\times1$ eigenvectors . So we still have $n$ equations but now $n\times n+n$ unknowns. Why can we “solve” this problem and determine $n\times n+n$ numbers from $n$ equations? I know I how to do it and have done it, but I’m confused why I CAN.

Basically, why can I solve this when it APPEARS to be way underdetermined?

Comment: The “basic problem in linear algebra” (arguable) would be solving a system of the form $Ax=b$, where $A$ is $n\times m$ and $b$ is $n\times 1$. It is simply not true that the basic problem is for systems of equations with the same number of equations as unknowns.

Comment: Underdetermined systems can also be solved. But in the case of eigenvalues, we are not merely trying to find solutions, we are trying to determine situations in which the system has **nontrivial** solutions, and that leads to a different problem, that of determining the values of $\lambda$ for which $A-\lambda I_n$ is not invertible. That is a *different* type of problem. Only after you determine those values of $\lambda$ do you attempt to solve $Ax=\lambda x$, at which point $\lambda$ is no longer an unknown.

Comment: To count $n^2$ unknowns because there are $n$ solutions, each an $n$-vector, is like saying $x^2=17$ has two unknowns because there are two solutions. $x^2=17$ doesn't have two unknowns, and $Ax=cx$ doesn't have $n^2+n$ unknowns.

Comment: It _is_ underdetermined. If $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then so is $a\mathbf v$ for all scalars $a\ne0$. That doesn’t mean that the system can’t be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on looking at the problem from the perspective of the "basic problem", note that in general each eigenvalue determines one eigenvector up to scale. It is also common to scale the eigenvectors so they are of unit length. So for each of $n$ eigenvalues we have $n+1$ equations, for $n^2+n$ equations in total.